# Navigating with cd and assigning a directory path to a shortcut variable name in Windows Bash

Tags: windows, bash

Is it possible to assign a directory path to a shortcut variable name that can be used to access quickly over and over again through commands like `cd`?

I am navigating consistently between several directories and I would like to avoid typing out the full directory path every time. I recall having the capacity to enter the shortcut for a path to access a commonly used directory in Linux. I was wondering if it is possible to use the same `cd [SHORTCUT_DIRECTORY_NAME]` in Windows Git-Bash or if there is an alternative permanent solution that would limit  typing out the full directory paths.

Here is an example of such command to access `C:\Users\[NAME]\Documents\common` directory in a linux machine shortened to `com`:

```
[USER]@DESKTOP /c/Users
$ cd com
[USER]@DESKTOP /c/Users/[NAME]/Documents/common
$
```

I have mostly found ways to use `.bat` files and I'm not sure this applies to Windows. I was thinking my next best bet would be trying to create a Shell script, but any input on the most convenient method would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Environment: Windows 10, Git Bash v. 4.4.12

Answer (score 0):

is this what you require:

you can assign the directory path to a string and do cd $string. Example:

sh-4.4$ dir="/home/cg/root/abc/xyz/tyh/"

sh-4.4$ pwd
/home/cg/root
sh-4.4$ cd $dir
sh-4.4$ pwd
/home/cg/root/abc/xyz/tyh